# Is Unobtanium an element or a compound?

Tags: avatar

Unobtanium is described as a ["highly valued mineral"](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Unobtanium) found on Pandora. But [according to the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral), "A mineral is a naturally occurring substance that is solid and representable by a chemical formula".

This description includes materials like Diamond which only contain one type of element (Carbon [**C**]), and materials like Quartz which are compounds (Silicon Dioxide [**SiO<sub>2</sub>**]).

I am not asking for any scientific proof, because that would be off topic here. But I would like to know if there is canonical information on the type of Unobtanium. Is Unobtanium an element or a compound?

Comment: It's [whatever writers need it to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium).

Comment: Nobody knows because scientists have - as yet - been unable to obtain any.

Comment: Answerers should note that this question is not asking for speculation or real-world science about a fictional substance: it's asking for "canonical information," meaning franchise-specific citations should be provided to back up answers given.

Comment: It is a floor wax *and* a dessert topping. "It tastes great! And just look at that shine!"

Comment: @phantom42: Unobtanium is not necessarily Unobtainium. :)

Comment: Technically, it's a McGuffin.

Comment: You'll get the answer in sequel..

Answer (score 20):

In the book *Avatar: An Activist Survival Guide* by Maria Wilhelm and Dirk Mathison, many topics about both the planet Pandora and the Na'vi culture are explained at more detail.

In the section **Astronomy and Geology**, Unobtanium is described as a **compound**.

Page 16:

> When the world's first high-temperature superconductor was created in the late twentieth century, it proved to be useless because of inherent instabilities. Further efforts proved futile, and researchers finally termed their goal “unobtainium” (the spelling was later changed to “unobtanium” to conform to chemical element naming, although **unobtanium is a compound, not an element**). There matters stood until the first unmanned exploration vehicle reached Alpha Centauri A and discovered deposits of a high-temperature superconducting substance on an Earth-like moon named Pandora—unobtanium had been obtained at last.

However, as noted by Richard, the same book in page 18 shows a picture of Unobtanium with a periodic table **element** shown as #120.

[image: Page 18 illustration showing a periodic table entry for Unm, atomic number 120]

So, given that the book is not consistent with itself, the answer is not clear. However, I think the first information has more prevalence, since it's meant to be read and understood, while the next picture is just for illustration purposes and not part of the main text.

Comment: It's described as "Element #120" on page 18 of **the same book**.

Comment: I can't find this info on my copy (a preview from the Web, but page 18 is present)

Comment: OK, I see it, it's in the main picture... So, if it's contradicting itself, what is the answer?

Comment: That's a very good question. You need to dig deeper if there's a canon contradiction. Are there any quotes from Cameron or any of the film's cast or crew, for example?

Comment: In the light of new info, I have to unaccept the answer. Sorry @ArturoTorresSánchez.

Comment: Ch. 15 of the officially-licensed "The Science of Avatar" also mentions that part of the backstory is that the Alpha Centauri system was "perturbed by an intruder, a runaway neutron star" early in its history, and that "the neutron star, itself a source of powerful magnetic fields, ripped into the young Centauri stars, and some bizarre nuclear reactions followed. The result was a system laced with unobtanium." So "nuclear reactions" suggests new elements involved, although it could still be a compound that just *included* a higher element than the ones we know.

Comment: The illustration also misspells the name of the cyclops giant who provided the name for the giant planet Pandora orbits -- which was "Polyphemus".